# jHipster + react application, change landing page to new one

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jhipster

I have created an application with jhipster + react. Its a default application generated by jHipster. How to change the default landing page(Home page) to a different page. How do I do it? I am quite new to react.

Comment: I am using jHipster version 6.6.0

Comment: Please edit your question with more details on what you want to achieve because here it's not clear whether you want to add a URL prefix or have two single page applications.

Comment: Its not single page application. I what to know how jhipster wired the home page so that I can change the landing page. I don't want to edit the existing home page.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not  clear. If you want to add a URL prefix (e.g "/admin") you could do it by setting the context-path in spring boot app properties and setting the baseHref in webpack conf. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path and https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#run